# Cant execute conditional query with shortestPath using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query:

```
MATCH (me:label1{userId:{1}})-[rel:nearby_group]-(group:GROUP)
WHERE NOT ((me)-[:relation_1|relation_2*1..3]-()--(group))
DELETE rel
```

ofcourse by Profiler I am getting lots of hits coz the second part of my query (the one after where not has lots of internal loops)

I wanted to improve it with shortestPath:

```
PROFILE 
MATCH (me:label1{userId:{1}})-[rel:nearby_group]-(group:GROUP)
WHERE NOT shortestPath((me)-[:relation_1|relation_2*1..3]-()--(group))
DELETE rel
```

but guess cant do it syntactically:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax
```

Any idea how can I use shortestPath in my query or improve it other way?

screenshot from profiler:

[image]

So I have modified  the query this way:

```
PROFILE 
    MATCH (me:label1{userId:{1}})-[rel:nearby_group]-(group:GROUP)
    WHERE NOT shortestPath((me)-[:relation_1|relation_2*1..3]-(group))
    DELETE rel
```

But iam getting an empty result.
I expected to see the following relationship to be deleted and it didnt:

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be correct, except the use of 2 colons here :

```
(me:BT{userId:{1}})-[rel:nearby_group]-(group:GROUP)
```

should be

```
PROFILE MATCH (me:BT{userId:{1}})-[rel:nearby_group]-(group:GROUP) where not shortestPath((me)-[:relation_1|relation_2*1..3]-()--(group)) delete rel
```

UPDATE :

Also, shortestPath doesn't accept multiple relationship patterns defninitions, it is much more like (a)-[:TO*]->(b)

This one works in my browser :

```
PROFILE MATCH (me:BT{userId:{1}})-[rel:nearby_group]-(group:GROUP) where not shortestPath((me)-[:relation_1|:relation_2*..3]-(group)) delete rel
```

shortestPath doc

> This means: find a single shortest path between two nodes, as long as
>   the path is max 15 relationships long. Inside of the parentheses you
>   define a single link of a path — the starting node, the connecting
>   relationship and the end node. Characteristics describing the
>   relationship like relationship type, max hops and direction are all
>   used when finding the shortest path. If there is a WHERE clause
>   following the match of a shortestPath, relevant predicates will be
>   included in the shortestPath. If the predicate is a NONE() or ALL() on
>   the relationship elements of the path, it will be used during the
>   search to improve performance

http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-shortest-path

Comment: I used your answer. still getting  Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax

Comment: I those 2 colons werent my syntax issue as it was just a typo when I wrote to here. modified my question and still same error

Comment: what do u mean by 'multiple relationship patterns definitions' ?

Comment: i tried it. it does compile but result return nothing. assume in the graph there is node with label BT which is connected with going-out relationship to node with label GROUP. this query should remove relations where u have a straight SINGLE connection from BT to GROUP (and no other relations btw them). and the deleted isnt executed